# On Row Click disable/enable a button depending on content of a cell in that row

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, flexigrid

I'm currently using the flexigrid.js plugin and there is a button that I wish to enable/disable depending on whether a certain cell in the currently selected row is equal to a certain value.

Here is where I am currently at: 
I thought to add  the following to the list of callback functions but am stuck as to what to put in the if statement if that is even a valid check.

```
'onRowClick': function(row,grid){
                        var content = $(row).attr('content');
                        if ($content == 'target'){

                        }
```

This callback function does not register though, the `'onDblClick':function...` does work however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer from [Marc Borgers](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=cU_zfRwAAABtSqeRtXJc3gtFbDJT3hVHpiKY4THuRnhmftpUpqxyyQ) from the [Flexigrid for jQuery](http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid/browse_thread/thread/23717d2e76650019) google group copied it here for reference

> In the colModel parameter of
>   flexigrid, you can pass a callback 
>   function with name process.  In that
>   function you can hook on a function
>   that is called when a row  is clicked.
>   I know it sounds difficult. An example
>   will make more clear. Here it is:

```
function procMe(celDiv,id) { 
        $(celDiv).click( 
                function () {alert(this.innerHTML + " " + id); } 
        ); 
}; 

function postFlexigrid() 
{ 
        $("#flex1").flexigrid 
                        ( 
                        { 
                        url: 'yourURL', 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        colModel : [ 
                                {display: 'Name', name : 'xxx', width : 200, sortable : false, 
align: 'left', process: procMe} 
                                ], 
                        usepager: false, 
                        singleSelect: true, 
                        title: 'x', 
                        useRp: false, 
                        showTableToggleBtn: true, 
                        height: 150 
                        } 
                        ); 
} 

$(document).ready(function() { 
        postFlexigrid(); 
});
```

> `procMe` will be called and if you click
>   on a row, an alert is shown.  Hope
>   this helps.
>   Regards, Marc